# Increasing viewport on lazy load detection

Tags: javascript

I'm using this script to lazy load  tags, I'm familiar with most of it but theres a section that I'm not quite sure about

```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
     var lazyloadImages;

     if ("IntersectionObserver" in window) {
       lazyloadImages = document.querySelectorAll(".lazy");
       var imageObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
         entries.forEach(function(entry) {
           if (entry.isIntersecting) {
             var image = entry.target;
             image.src = image.dataset.src;
             image.classList.remove("lazy");
             imageObserver.unobserve(image);
           }
         });
       });

       lazyloadImages.forEach(function(image) {
         imageObserver.observe(image);
       });
     } else {
       var lazyloadThrottleTimeout;
       lazyloadImages = document.querySelectorAll(".lazy");

       function lazyload () {
         if(lazyloadThrottleTimeout) {
           clearTimeout(lazyloadThrottleTimeout);
         }

         lazyloadThrottleTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
           var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
           lazyloadImages.forEach(function(img) {
               if(img.offsetTop < (window.innerHeight + scrollTop)) {
                 img.src = img.dataset.src;
                 // img.classList.remove('lazy');
               }
           });
           if(lazyloadImages.length == 0) {
             document.removeEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
             window.removeEventListener("resize", lazyload);
             window.removeEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
           }
         }, 20);
       }

       document.addEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
       window.addEventListener("resize", lazyload);
       window.addEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
     }
   })
```

Currently it will load an `<img>` if it enters the bottom of the viewport. I'd prefer if it loaded imgs ahead, say 200px - 300px below the view port so the user doesn't see the load happening.

I thinking it has to do with this part

```
if(img.offsetTop < (window.innerHeight + scrollTop))
```

I don't know what these values mean so I'm not sure how to specify to start the lazy load 200px ahead.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(img.offsetTop < (window.innerHeight + scrollTop + 250))
```